# How to fix this json email pattern

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, validation, design-patterns

I'm creating Collection USER where he is asked to add an email field.

This is what I have in the validation collection.

```
db.createCollection("user", {
validator: {
    $jsonSchema : {
        bsonType: "object", 
        required: ["email"],
    properties: {
        "email": {type: "string", pattern: "^(\\([a-z] {30}\\))?[a-z]{30}@[.]$"}
}}}})
```

I expect MongoDB to accept email in "email@email.com" format. The validation does not allow such a pattern.

```
WriteResult({
"nInserted" : 0,
"writeError" : {
    "code" : 121,
    "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect MongoDB to accept email in "email@email.com" format

That's technically an [ADDR_SPEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) rather than an email address, so kudos for clarifying exactly what you are asking about. Even if you are only talking about a single SMTP ADDR_SPEC (there are other kinds of email address) the syntax is still [very flexible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/testing123/2009/02/06/email-address-test-cases/).

While you could use a catch-all solution ([this](https://emailregex.com/) works for most cases) you probably want to exclude quoted mailbox names, exclude numeric IP addresses and require a fully qualified DNS name, hence something along the lines of:

```
/[a-z0-9\._%+!$&*=^|~#%{}/\-]+@([a-z0-9\-]+\.){1,}([a-z]{2,22})/
```

(and you might want to add anchors to disallow leading/training whitespace unless you are trimming the string elsewhere)

(But do note that this does not prove that the address has an MX record, nor that the SMTP server at that address will accepot emails for the mailbox, nor that the person supplying the data is in control of the mailbox)

Comment: Your pattern worked after my modification 
[a-z0-9\._%+!$&*=^|~#%{}\\-]+@([a-z0-9\-]+\.){1,}([a-z]{2,22}). Specificly in this part ~#%{}\\-]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should probably use a regular expression instead of a string in the creation of the validator. See [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) document, it's not documented very well but there is an example under Query Expressions section showing how to define a regex validation.

You should also consider that validating emails is a pretty complex operation, and most, if not all regexes will always filter out valid emails. You should usually choose a more defensive approach on email validation, so you don't end up losing valid emails.

You can find a list of email regex [here](http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20) and choose the one that best suits your needs

Comment: The second link has an answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For json-schema validator, you can use the `format` feature as an alternative approach:

```
validator: {
    $jsonSchema : {
        bsonType: "object", 
        required: ["email"],
    properties: {
        "email": {type: "string", format: "email"}
}}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern does not validate email you can check it on

> https://regex101.com/

use this regex =  ^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$ in pattern

hope it help

Comment: your regex not cover emails like this name+mod@gmail.com